# Traditional Chinese Typefaces

Tags: fonts, typography, chinese

I was looking for a cursive calligraphy traditional Chinese font which has a 萬 (ten thousand) character which is in the style of that on a standard Taiwanese or Cantonese Mahjong tiles.  So far I have only found non-cursive fonts.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "cursive". Do you mean "looks like the symbols were hand-written"? Or a "serif-type look"? Please advise.

Answer (score 5):

You might try one of the calligraphic Traditional Chinese fonts from [here](https://www.freechinesefont.com/category/calligraphy/) or [here](https://chinesefontdesign.com/tag/calligraphy-chinese-font).  For instance, a sample of [Senty Wen](https://sentyfont.com/sentywennew.htm) (which is only *gratis* for personal use).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newfontfamily\hantfont{SentyWen}[
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
  Script=CJK,
  Language={Chinese Traditional} ]

\newunicodechar{^^^^842c}{{\hantfont\symbol{"842C}}} % 萬

\begin{document}
萬 
\end{document}
```

[image: Senty Wen sample]

You can also give it an alias if you prefer.

```
\newcommand\texttenthousand{{\hantfont\symbol{"842C}}}
\newunicodechar{^^^^842c}{\texttenthousand\relax} % 萬
```

This template can easily be modified to test any glyphs from any font.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am copying your solution exactly and XeTeX is unable to compile it for some reason.  I am trying to use it in tikzpicture :  should this cause a problem?

Comment: @TroyW. Did you download the font? Can `fc-match "SentyWen"` find it? What error message are you getting?

Comment: @TroyW. Within a `tikzpicture`, you probably want to use the `node font=` command from section 17.4.2 of the [TikZ manual.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add some more info to the excellent answer by Davislor, [I.PenCrane-B](http://founder.acgvlyric.org/iu/doku.php/%E9%80%A0%E5%AD%97:%E9%96%8B%E6%BA%90%E5%AD%97%E5%9E%8B_i.%E9%8B%BC%E7%AD%86%E9%B6%B4%E9%AB%94) and [I.Ngaan](http://founder.acgvlyric.org/iu/doku.php/%E9%80%A0%E5%AD%97:%E9%96%8B%E6%BA%90%E5%AD%97%E5%9E%8B_i.%E9%A1%8F%E9%AB%94) are calligraphic fonts released under a GPL License (download files include both GPL2.0 and GPL3.0) so they are available for commercial use.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%Other font features aren't working with (Xe/Lua)TeX
\newfontfamily\TestA{I.PenCrane-B}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\newfontfamily\TestB{I.Ngaan}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\begin{document}
\textcolor[rgb]{0.8,0,0}{{\TestA 萬} {\TestB 萬}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. NIce touch to color the glyphs red -- just like real Mahjong tiles. :-)

Comment: Nice! Thanks, I wasn’t aware of them.

Comment: Neither of the fonts you link to supports any OpenType features, I’m afraid, or lets you choose between Traditional or Simplified Chinese. That said, the warning you’ll get if you try to do it anyway is harmless.